# What to do with matlab ode45 and symfun error?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, error-function

I am using code from adress 
http://matlab.cheme.cmu.edu/2011/09/08/plane-poiseuille-flow-bvp-solve-by-shooting-method//

but every time when I want to execute it I got:

'Undefinied function 'exist' for input arguments of type 'symfun'.

Error in odearguments line 59, if (exist(ode)==2).

Error in ode45 line 113 [neq,tspan,ntsoan,next,t0,tfinal,tdir...]

I have not idea what to do? I checked, my matlab version has symbolic mathtoolbox.

Comment: Why do you want to use a symbolic expression inside a numerical solver? `ode45` expects a function it can evaluate. Please post your code or the difference of your code to the linked code.

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365603/matlab-how-does-ode45-work on how you can do it if no other way is possible.